# getDeclaredMethod not found when using javassist

Tags: javassist

I have the following commented line:

```java
// "       java.lang.reflect.Method m = cls.getDeclaredMethod(\"valueOf\", boolean.class);",
```

If I uncomment this line I get an getDeclaredMethod not found:

```
javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] getDeclaredMethod(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class) not found in java.lang.Class
        at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:806)
        at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:766)
        at metron.Javassist_Bug.premain(Javassist_Bug.java:31)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:513)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
Caused by: compile error: getDeclaredMethod(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class) not found in java.lang.Class
        at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(TypeChecker.java:777)
        at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:723)
        at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:170)
        at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:49)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:266)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atDeclarator(CodeGen.java:819)
        at javassist.compiler.ast.Declarator.accept(Declarator.java:103)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:381)
        at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:53)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:381)
        at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:53)
        at javassist.compiler.MemberCodeGen.atTryStmnt(MemberCodeGen.java:234)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:397)
        at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:53)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:381)
        at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:53)
        at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:578)
        at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:786)
        ... 8 more
```

The code that is in main, where I do basically the same thing works fine.
I get the sense that this is either a javassist bug or limitation.
Could someone confirm?

```java
package metron;

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import javassist.*;


public class Javassist_Bug {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // this works:
        try {
            Class<?> cls = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
            System.out.println(cls.getName());
            java.lang.reflect.Method m = cls.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf", boolean.class);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // swallow exception
        }
    }


    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {

        try {
            ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
            CtClass cc = pool.get("java.lang.Thread");

            CtMethod m_start = cc.getDeclaredMethod("start");
            
            m_start.insertBefore(String.join("\n",
                "{",
                "   try {",
                "       Class cls = Class.forName(\"java.lang.String\");", // Class<?> does not work!
                "       System.out.println(cls.getName());",
                // "       java.lang.reflect.Method m = cls.getDeclaredMethod(\"valueOf\", boolean.class);",
                "   }",
                "   catch (Exception e) {",
                "       // swallow exception",
                "   }",
                "}"
            ));

            cc.writeFile("./bin");

            System.out.println("\n\nwrote new Thread class!\n\n");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I think it is a bug in javassist, I will dig down further later, I will update info here: https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/issues/396